# What is the difference between calling exampleFunction() and exampleFunction.call()?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

What is the difference between calling **exampleFunction()** and **exampleFunction.call()** ?
There is a feature on Actionscript that allows you to use functions through the 'call' method. For example, to use the 'test' function below, I could write **test()** and **test.call()**

```
function test():void {
 trace('function was called')
}
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As with ECMAScript (from which AS is derived) it allows specifying the "this" context via the first parameter.

See the [Function.call](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html) documentation. Note the remarks about functions vs. methods – or ["bound functions"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f30.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa5) – and the examples.

That is, given:

```
function f ():* { return this; }
var x:Object = {f: f};
```

Then:

Both `f.call(x)` and `x.f()` evaluate to `x` while `f()` does not as it has a different "this" (it evaluates to `Global` instead).

If `f.call()` (no params) is used then "this" will be NaN while `f()`, as per above, has `Global` as "this". Try using `trace(this)` in the test code as it will yield more useful contextual information.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Note also that the .call() method seems about 10x slower, according to this study by Jackson Dunstan :
http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/912

Comment: Chris, you should probably summarize the article, as answers where the entire answer is in a link are frowned on by StackOverflow and may be removed.

Comment: Thank you for training a newbee. Also my post was meant to complement pst's very good answer, but I wasn't allowed to comment on his answer.

Answer (score 1):

The practical difference comes in when you are passing functions around and you want to use them dynamically, though apply() is more commonly used for this, since it allows you to construct your list of arguments more dynamically.

Check out this article for more information on some situations where you might want to use these methods http://www.developria.com/2010/12/functional-actionscript-part-1.html